# Getting a JSON object to bind a Gridview of Asp.net insert/Edit/Update With groupping

Tags: json, json.net

I am new to JSON. Need Help.

1. How to bind a object to `GridView` and proceed with DML operation in `GridView`? I have a custom grid with `TextBox` and `DropDownList` and Grouping functionality.
2. Do we need a Web Service for interaction to DB (Sql) Inserting/Updating/Deleting if JSON is used? Can we read the data directly from UI and send it to DB?
3. Will it support inner functions like : `ISNULL(SubString(FieldName,Param1,Param2))`?

In my current prototype I have implemented it with normal ASP controls for UI like `GridView`, `TextBox` etc. I have a Custom `Gridview` with `TextBox` and `DropDowList` in Edit mode.

Comment: Can you tell me where are you using or planning to use Json in point 1 and 2. Regarding the point 3, you can use the normal string functions for string related operations. Can you please elaborate with a small example

Comment: Hi, In Point 1 . We will get data as Json Object base and Binding to Controls. After Serialization JSOn object (Select * from Emp (if 10 rows comes) using JSON how to bind in Grid view and other controls). 2. While entering a new data to db how connect Sql server directly or using webmethod only

Comment: This seems outside the scope of JSon. you might want to add more tag to get better answer like C#, ASP.Net etc. Also edit your question with code sample.